# Including QML plugin into project

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QML plugin project and my application project plus `subdirs` project organized like that:

```
project.pro
plugin/
    plugin.pro
    Plugin.cpp
    Plugin.h
    qmldir
app/
    app.pro
    main.cpp
    main.qml
    qml.qrc
```

`project.pro`:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS = app plugin
app.depends = plugin
```

`plugin.pro`:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
QT += qml quick
CONFIG += plugin c++11

TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget(plugin)
PLUGIN_URI = com.test.plugin

SOURCES += Plugin.cpp
HEADERS += Plugin.h
```

`app.pro`:

```
QT += qml quick

SOURCES += main.cpp
RESOURCES += qml.qrc
```

It builds as expected and now I need to pass path to compiled `libplugin.dylib`/`.so`/`.dll` and `qmldir` to my application. I see two ways:

1. Copy plugin files into /path/to/qt/5.10.1/clang_64/qml/com/test/plugin/ using INSTALL qmake variable.
2. Copy plugin files near the application executable and add this path as relative to the executable using `QQmlEngine::addImportPath()`.

What approach will be better? How to do it?

Comment: I usually do "import path" environment variable I set either in the project or in Qt Creator or then some installation guy sets it with the run script. Find it here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-imports.html Works for both Qt's own and ours. But I cannot just put that as an answer as long as it is neither #1 or #2 of yours. `QML_IMPORT_PATH2`. And of course if set in the project you should rather try to make it relative.